# Which is correct? Users who or Users that?

Tags: word-choice

I'm often confused by the correct use for "who" and "that".  I believed always that "who" in a sentence refers to people or persons and "that" refers to inanimate objects, machines, animals, etc.

In the case of:  "SATA III SSD drives are ideal for users **that** demand maximum performance." I believe should read: "SATA III SSD drives are ideal for users **who** demand maximum performance."

Gregg

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108402/how-to-avoid-that-that-that-that-is-so-very-awkward/108416#108416

Comment: [Either one is all right](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html). There's no difference; _that_ can substitute for either human _who_ or nonhuman _which_ in restrictive relative clauses. _That_ can't be used in non-restrictive relative clauses at all, but they're much less common than restrictive relative clauses. Like these.