# Meaning of "-'s" in "that's had cake"

Tags: meaning, contractions

Below a part of subtitles from the *Angry Birds* movie.

> 77 00:04:25,400 --> 00:04:26,435 Get outta here!
>
> 78 00:04:26,520 --> 00:04:28,440 **Already? But you're the only one
>   that's had cake.**
>
> 79 00:04:28,480 --> 00:04:29,480 What...
>
> 80 00:04:29,640 --> 00:04:30,640 Mmm.
>
> 81 00:04:31,040 --> 00:04:32,268 Oh, that's good stuff.

Can you please tell me what "-'s" is in the bold sentence above? Does "-'s" represent "has", "is" or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"That's" in this context is a contraction for "that has."

"Already? But you're the only one that has had cake."

Comment: Absolutely correct, but it's worth saying that the usage is colloquial and ungrammatical. In standard English it would be 'You're the only only one  _who's_ had cake', but probably _that's_ would be more commonly used. Perhaps this is what confused the OP.

Comment: @BoldBen Janus Bahs Jacquet's accepted answer at [Choice of relative pronouns: 'who' and/or 'that' for people?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174933/choice-of-relative-pronouns-who-and-or-that-for-people) says that 'Restrictive clauses ... can take both pronominal and non-pronominal relativisers (i.e., 'that' or 'wh-words') with no real difference in meaning or usage.'